# How do I load data into models from server rendered html

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have html that is generated from the server using Node.js, express, and precompiled Handlebars templates. How do I get that data into my Ember Models?

Comment: Are you using Ember Model or Ember Data?

Comment: @kingpin2k Neither as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this during the application ready hook.  Get the data from the page using jquery.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function(){
   // The DOM is ready, this is called before the route is resolved etc 
  }
});
```

And then depending on your client side record management, you can sideload it using one of the following methods (for the album model).

Ember Data:

```
var store = this.get('store'); 

store.push('album', {
  id: 1,
  title: "Fewer Moving Parts",
  artist: "David Bazan",
  songCount: 10
});
```

Ember Model:

```
App.Album.load([{
  id: 1,
  title: "Fewer Moving Parts",
  artist: "David Bazan",
  songCount: 10
}]);
```

Comment: So to be clear, on `ready`, I am basically scraping the page for data and inserting into the appropriate model? Is this considered the best practice? Thanks!

Comment: If you are injecting the data into the page, it's the best way to handle it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass data on server rendered HTML, the best way would be to include a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    myAppData = {
        data1 = ['name1' , 'name2'],
        data2 = {
            id = 5
        }
    }
</script>
```

Or something like that.
You can then use your Ember.Application's instance init method to pass use this data.

Comment: Meori, his question was how to load the data, not how to inject the data into the page.